# AC output from the following buck-converter?

Tags: ac, dc-dc-converter

Will the output be 100% DC from this buck-converter? Or Am I missing a diode bridge?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjkS8U.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A friend pointed out that the buck-converter would output AC, I'm doubtful and maybe it's because the diode bridge is missing?

Comment: No, it will output AC because it will be impossible to entirely filter the AC component from the signal.

Comment: Is this a failed DC/DC buck converter circuit? I know that buck converters of DC input will output DC?

Comment: They output DC with an AC component.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Although can be filtered to a point where the AC is completely negligible? And the DC output is the only focused?

Answer (score 1):

It will be DC with a some ripple depending upon the inductor value, frequency and the value and quality of the output capacitor.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the AC output ripple to a negligible point more than with just a capacitor, use a linear regulator following the buck converter.